# I delete one item from list,also same item is deleted from another list in AngularJs

Tags: javascript

I have two list.Both of them are filled with my service.My service like this:

My service:

```
 `function data (){

   var locationList={
           list: ''
   }
   var currentlocation = {
         editList : ''
   }

return {


       getAllLocationList:function(){

           return locationList.list;
       },

      setAllLocationList:function(allLocationList){
          locationList.list = allLocationList; 
       },

       getCurrentList:function(){

           return currentlocation.editList;
       },

      setCurrentList:function(currentList){
          currentlocation.editList = currentList; 
       },

  }
 }`
```

In my controller,

```
vm.location=data.getCurrentList();
vm.allLocationList=data.getAllLocationList();
```

vm.location contains id,name,keywords,number and 
vm.allLocationList contains name,keywords,number

I have also keywordAdd and keywordDelete functions.When i enter keywordDelete function and when i delete some keywords from `vm.location`list,then automatically same items is deleted from `vm.allLocationList`.Same situation is valid on keywordAdd function. Do you have any idea?Maybe, service structure is not good.I wrote this for the first time.
I have been working for 2 days.It is not solved.

Comment: How are you setting the ```var locationList``` and ```var currentlocation``` inside the function? my guess is that you are setting them to the same object

Comment: I wrote a service to transfer data between controller.Not same different objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is about [Javascript execution context](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/). When you create a function, the variables inside it belong to it in it's context. Meaning they will be similar for every instance of `data()`.

Javascript (since ES5 I think) supported Object Oriented programming, letting you create an object and then multiple, (semi-)separate instances.

```
function Data() {
   this.locationList={
           list: ''
   }
   this.currentlocation = {
         editList : ''
   }
}

Data.prototype = {
       getAllLocationList:function(){
           return this.locationList.list;
       },
      setAllLocationList:function(allLocationList){
          this.locationList.list = allLocationList; 
       },
       getCurrentList:function(){
           return this.currentlocation.editList;
       },
      setCurrentList:function(currentList){
          this.currentlocation.editList = currentList; 
       },
 }

var data = new Data();
```

I strongly recommend doing some further reading on this subject. It is the core of many JS confusions. Good luck!

Comment: In each controller, if i want to use this service, do i have to create an object like this:  `var obj=new Data();` after that to get data `obj.prototype.getAllLocationList()`

Comment: When I use prototype to assign functions to my object, is only due to the Javascript syntax - which you can fully read about if you look up "Javascript Objects". In general I really recommend "Do You Know JS" if you're looking into more deep-hands on development with the language.

Comment: So yes, you will create it like that and the usage will look like that: `obj.getAllLocationList()`.